# Computation of $H^*_c(\mathcal{M}_{1,[2]},\mathbb{V}_1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-group-theory, moduli-spaces, group-cohomology

As a term of a Serre spectral sequence, I would like to compute the cohomology group with compact support $H^*_c(\mathcal{M}_{1,[2]},\mathbb{V}_1)$ of the moduli space of genus $1$ curves with $2$ unordered marked points, with values in $\mathbb{V}_1$, the standard representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, coming from the cohomology group $H^1(E,\mathbb{Q})$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve.

I know that $H^*_c(\mathcal{M}_{1,1},\mathbb{V}_1)=0$, and I would like to try to use this result to obtain a similar one for the case of $2$ unordered marked points.

My attempt so far consists in using mapping class groups, the Birman exact sequence

\begin{equation*}
1\to \pi_1(S_{1,1})\to \text{PMod}(S_{1,2})\to \text{PMod}(S_{1,1})\to 1
\end{equation*}
and the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence of group cohomology, to obtain $H^*(\mathcal{M}_{1,2},\mathbb{V}_1)$ (which I believe to be identically $0$), using the fact that the action of the fibre $\pi_1(S_{1,1})\cong \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ on the local system is trivial, as $\mathbb{V}_1$ is a representation of $\text{PMod}(S_{1,1})\cong SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Since I am not used to mapping class groups and group cohomology, I have, now, two questions:

1. Is the reasoning so far correct?
2. Assuming it is, this takes care only of the moduli stack $\mathcal{M}_{1,2}$ with ordered points. How do I obtain the cohomology of the unordered one? I think that would consist in getting rid of the action of the elliptic involution, exchanging the marked points, but it is not clear to me how to effectively do it.

To be coherent with other results I have, I would hope this cohomology groups not to be identically $0$.

I would appreciate any comment on my problem, or any helpful reference for the computation of $H^*_c(\mathcal{M}_{1,[2]},\mathbb{V}_1)$, also with other methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is good but you must have messed something up with the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.

I prefer the sheafy approach over thinking about the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, so let me explain it in these terms. So we have the forgetful map $\pi : M_{1,2} \to M_{1,1}$, and we may write
$$ H^\bullet_c(M_{1,2},V) = H^\bullet_c(M_{1,1},R\pi_!V ).$$
Now $V=\pi^\ast V$ is actually pulled back from $M_{1,1}$ and we have $$R\pi_! \pi^\ast V \cong (R\pi_!\mathbf Q) \otimes V \cong (V \otimes V)[-1] \oplus V(-1)[-2]$$
where in the first step we used the projection formula and in the second we used a section to split $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ in the derived category. Representation theory of $\mathrm{SL}(2)$ shows that $V \otimes V \cong V_2 \oplus \mathbf Q(-1)$, where $V_2$ is the second symmetric power of $V$ and $\mathbf Q(-1)$ is a Tate twist of the trivial representation. From the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism we know $H^\bullet_c(M_{1,1},-)$ with coefficients taken in all of these summands: $H^2_c(M_{1,1},\mathbf Q(-1)) \cong \mathbf Q(-2)$, $H^1_c(M_{1,1},V_2)\cong \mathbf Q(0)$, all other cohomologies vanish. So $H^\bullet_c(M_{1,2},V)$ is $\mathbf Q(-2)$ in degree $3$, $\mathbf Q(0)$ in degree $2$, and vanishes otherwise.

To deal with unordered points we use that $H^\bullet_c(M_{1,[2]},V) = H^\bullet_c(M_{1,2},V)^{\Sigma_2}$, where $\Sigma_2$ acts by permuting the markings. Unfortunately the computation in the previous paragraph isn't immediately $\Sigma_2$-equivariant. But in fact $\Sigma_2$ acts on $M_{1,2}$ preserving the map $\pi$; it acts by multiplication by $-1$ on the universal elliptic curve. To see this we consider a curve with two marked points $(x,y)$. We can translate to make the first coordinate the origin, and our markings are then $(0,y-x)$. Clearly if we had swapped $x$ and $y$ we would have gotten $x-y$ instead. Inversion in $V$ acts as the identity on $V \otimes V$, so $H^\bullet_c(M_{1,[2]},V) = H^\bullet_c(M_{1,2},V)$.

Hope this is coherent with other results you have!

Comment: Thank you for your precise and quick answer! I indeed care about Tate twists too. On that note, could you please explain how did you obtain those? I would assume $H^2_c(M_{1,1},\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Q}(-1)$ already, but I can't see how to deduce the twists on $H^k_c(M_{1,2},V)$.

Comment: OK! I put them in.

Comment: You mentioned that to split $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ in corresponding derived category one have to use certain section. Could you lose few words on why such section in the setting above must always exist?

Comment: I was being very sloppy and careless. To split it, it's enough to have a multisection of degree 1 on each fiber, so you could e.g. take 1/3 times the sum of the 2-torsion points on your elliptic curves. Or you could work with a continuous section rather than an algebraic section. Or you could simply ignore trying to split $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ in the derived category; for our purposes it's enough that the Leray-Serre spectral sequence degenerates, which is obvious in this case as there is no room for a nonzero differential on the $E_2$ page.

Comment: The last argument with LS-spectral seq of course works but 
I would like to understand better this first splitting approach, 
since I'm not sure if I completely got it. So far we want to 
get a split of $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$, the naive approach is to
to find a splitting of a distinguished triangle carrying 
$R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ as middle term. If such dist triangle comes
from a "geometric" morphism $f: X \to S$ like in our case with 
$\pi$, then the "classical" trick from homological algebra
to obtain a split is to find a section of $f$.

Comment: (That's what one often applies to obtain splittings of exact sequences even without passing to derived level) But so far I undrstand your point correctly in derived setting even a multisection of degree $1$ in every fiber already suffice to obtain the splitting of $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$, so in setting above we need a $D \subset M_{1,2}$ with 
restricted projection $\pi$ to $D$ quasi-finite + (some technical 
assumtions to make this map "finite cover like"). If what I 
wrote so far reflects your idea correctly, why such a multisection 
already gives split of $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ in derived setting?

Comment: by the way probably another stupid question: isn't a multisection 
with degree 1 in every fiber not the same as honest section? 
( at least when geometry is sufficient nice, ie no nonreduced 
phenomena not occure etc, or do I missing some important point?)

Comment: Probably "degree 1 multisection" was misleading. I can act on $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ by a $\mathbf Q$-linear combination of cycles. For example, the $2$-torsion of the universal elliptic curve defines a multisection of degree $3$, and I'm allowed to act by $1/3$ times this multisection.

Comment: Could you explain how this action on $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$ by $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of cycles/ $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors of the universal elliptic curve is concretely given? (maybe this resolves my confusion)

Comment: Also I'm not sure in which sense the $2$-torsion part has degree $3$. By 'degree' you refer to the usual degree of divisor? Then, so far I understand it correctly the degree refers to the degree of each fiber (=$E/\mathbb{Q}$) of the universal elliptic curve. But the $2$-torsion of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $E[2]=\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, so shouldn't the degree of $2$-torsion of universal ell curve not be $4$, or do you in your last comment not taking the "neutral group element" into account?

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer. The action by algebraic cycles is a fiberwise version of the usual way that algebraic correspondences act on cohomology, by "pushing and pulling". My paper with Mehdi Tavakol and Qizheng Yin is maybe helpful about this. I.e. think about how $CH(X \times X)$ forms an algebra by compositions of correspondences and $H(X)$ is a module over it, and do a relative version for a family of varieties $X\to S$.

Comment: Regarding the 2-torsion, since $\pi$ is the projection from the universal *punctured* elliptic curve, the origin is not included and we include only the nontrivial 2-torsion points, hence degree $3$. But maybe it's easier to replace $\pi$ with the projection from the universal elliptic curve, say $\overline\pi : E \to M_{1,1}$. This family has an honest section so it's easier to split $R\overline \pi_\ast\mathbf Q$ in the derived category, and then one could argue that a decomposition of $R\overline \pi_\ast\mathbf Q$ induces one of $R\pi_!\mathbf Q$.

Comment: I see, so this action is compatible with fibers and comes indeed
from the "usual" action by Chow groups of an ellipt curve
$E/\mathbb{Q}$ on cohomology groups since
$(R\pi_*\mathbf Q)_y = H^*(E, O_E)$ 
(later holds by proper base change argument for $\pi$) where
$y$ corresp to $E$ in moduli space).

Comment: Let's focus on this non relative case only. 
What I not understand 
completely is why splitting of 
$H^*(E, O_E)$ follows from existence of
a multisection/divisor $D$ on $E$. 
If it is a "geometrical" section, then it's classical, we not even need to impose this action by Chow cycles, we simply use that cohomology is functorial.
But what if $D$ has degree bigger than one? 
So far I understand
here the trick is to extend the coefficients from
$\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ and then to make
multisections "virtually" of degree $1$ as 
$\mathbb{Q}$-divisors.

Comment: Why such a $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor - say $D/\text{deg}(D)$ -
"normed" to degree $1$ gives always a split
of $H^*(E, O_E)$ acting as Chow cycle on it? Or equivalently 
in terms of this action, why all such 
$\mathbb{Q}$-divisors of degree $1$ give idempotent 
Chow cycles even not coming from honest sections?

Comment: I'm still a bit pondering about this what you said about this action: so do I understand it correctly that taking any effective divisor $D \subset E$ and dividing it's degree, so making it to a Q-divisor of degree $1$ induces always(!) an idempotent endo in terms of this action via correspondences you described above? So is a Q-divisor of degree $1$ iff it acts as an idempotent?

Comment: If yes, could you give a reference or sketch the idea? If it is a bit lengthy and you have time I opened a separate question on this problem here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447890/correspondences-acting-on-cohomology-groups-hx-splittings. sorry for annoying, I would like to understand absolutely this point better