# Correspondences acting on cohomology groups $H^*(X)$ & splittings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth connected proper scheme over field $k$. It is known that
correspondences $\alpha \subset X \times X$ regarded as
objects in Chow groups $\text{CH}^*(X \times X)$
act on cohomology $H^*(X, \mathbb{Z})$ via "push and pull",
namely we have a cycle class map

$$ \text{cl}:  \text{CH}^*(X) \to H^*(X, \mathbb{Z} )  $$

which is compatible with pull-backs & push-forwards. If
$p_1, p_2: X \times X \to X $ are the projections and $\alpha $
a correspondence in $X \times X$, then it acts as

$$ \alpha^*: H^*(X \mathbb{Z}) \to H^*(X \mathbb{Z}), \ \ \ 
\alpha^*(s) := p_{2*}(p^*_1(s) \cap \text{cl}(\alpha)) $$

Clearly this action extends linearly to action by *rational*
Chow groups $\text{CH}_r^*(-)= \text{CH}^* \otimes \mathbb{Q}  $
on rational cohomology.

Let now specialize: Assume $X$ is a smooth proper curve and $D \subset X$
an effective divisor of degree $d$, ie a "multisection".
By dividing the degree $\beta:= \frac{1}{d} \cdot D $ becomes a
$\mathbb{Q}$-divisor of degree $1$, so a "virtual" section.

So far I understand it correctly in the [discussion here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443274)
Dan Petersen uses that the induced action by
such $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor of degree $1$ in terms from above
as associated Chow correspondence
induces a splitting of the cohomology. (Dan Petersen used this more generally in relative setting
& associated action on derived object $Rf_* \mathbb{Q}$ but for
sake of simplicity I would like to understand it in absolute case for a
single curve as baby version of this mechanism.)

Question: I not see why this action gives a splitting of the cohomology?
In other words does such $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor "normed" to degree $1$
induce an idempotent endomorphism corresponding
to the associated action described above? It seems that the degree $1$ assumption is crucial, but I not see the connection. Then it would mean that every effective divisor turned into degree $1$ $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor by dividing it's degree would acting idempotently on the cohomology, ie give a splitting of the cohomology? That seems strange. Maybe I misunderstood somewhere Dan Petersen's argument.

Comment: Certainly $D \times X$ is an idempotent endomorphism and $X \times D $ is another idempotent endomorphism if $X$ is proper (or maybe, depending on conventions, the other way around). The degree $D$ being one is necessary to get idempotence. Otherwise you would get the relation $E^2 = E \cdot \deg D$ for $E$ the endomporphism.

Comment: @WillSawin: But is degree $1$ assumption  also sufficeient? Intuitively it's not obvious to me, but it seems that's what Dan Petersen used (compare with comment #4 in the linked discussion below the answer). It seems that he took an arbitrary effective divisor, divided it's degee in order to norm it's degree to one, and this should already give the splitting.

Comment: (yes, $X$ can be assumed as proper)

Comment: Sufficient for what? It's easy to calculate the composition to check that $D \times X$ is idempotent, and every idempotent gives a splitting.

Comment: @WillSawin: I not understand how to see that $D \times X $ gives idempotent endomorphism if we assume that $D$ has degree one as Q-divisor, Could you sketch the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composition of a correspondence in $X \times Y$ and a correspondence in $Y \times Z$ is given by pulling both back to $X\times Y\times Z$, intersecting them, and pushing forward to $X \times Z$.

To check that $ D\times X \subset X\times X$ is idempotent under composition for $D$ of degree $1$, we pull back along two projections $X\times X \times X \to X\times X$, obtaining $D \times X \times X$ and $X\times D \times X$, then intersect $D \times X \times X$ and $X\times D \times X$, obtaining $D \times D \times X$, then finally pushforward $D \times D \times X$ along the projection to $X \times X$, which gives $D\times X$.

Here we use that for a cycle on $X \times Y \times Z$ obtained as a product of $A$ on $X\times Z$ with $B$ on $Y$, the pushforward to $X\times Z$ is $A$ times the degree of $B$. So this is where the degree enters into the picture.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can find discussed in many references on Chow motives. For example you can look at "On the motive of an algebraic surface" by Murre, §1.5 "Splitting off the trivial parts".

In general, if $X$ is a smooth projective variety then any zero-cycle $\mathfrak z$ on $X$ will define a correspondence $\mathfrak z \times X$ from $X$ to itself. It is idempotent iff $\deg \mathfrak z=1$, and working with $\mathbf Q$-coefficients we may assume this. This idempotent acts on several things: the motive $h(X)$, but also more closely related to your question, the object $C^\bullet(X)$ in the derived category. The image of this idempotent splits off $H^0$. Its transpose splits off $H^{2\dim(X)}$. If $X$ only has cohomology in three degrees we get a decomposition in the derived category. Now splitting the object $C^\bullet(X)$ is typically not so interesting, as every chain complex is quasi-isomorphic to its cohomology. But in a relative setting it is more nontrivial.

Comment: Could recommend some sources treating the relative case?

Comment: I can't really think of anything, no.